# upload zip file to ckan using java

Tags: java, content-type, ckan

I have a working java application that uploads a text file to a ckan installation using this code.

```
File file = new File("path/testFile.txt")
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file ,ContentType.TEXT_HTML);
HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
           .addPart("file", cbFile) 
           .build();
postRequest = new HttpPost(HOST+"/api/action/resource_create");
postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
postRequest.setHeader("X-CKAN-API-Key", myApiKey);         
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(postRequest);
```

When i try to change the text file to a zip file, i get a 500 error, "server Error"

I am guessing this is because of the `ContentType`. I tried to find alternatives but nothing seems to work. Tried to create my own like so

```
ContentType zipType=ContentType.create("application/zip");
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file ,zipType);
```

But still didnt work.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
It seems that there is an issue with the file size. my program works as it is for small zip files (<5KB). I am not sure if this is a java or a ckan issue. Any help?

Comment: Where you Define File Size limit on xml or java code ??

Comment: nowhere. I didnt define file size, dont think so at least

Comment: for small size zip it will work or not ?

Comment: yes, for zip files smaller than 4 KB works OK

Comment: where did u mapped for upload the file on web.xml or struts ?

Comment: i am only using java and Apache HttpPost, nothing else. what do you mean where i mapped for upload?

Comment: Set Using final long Zip_SIZE = 5242880;

Comment: @AnandDwivedi how should i use this? looking for it online gives me no useful results

Comment: @AnandDwivedi sorry man, i cant understand what you are saying. "Where long Zip_SIZE is a variable where you store the uploaded file data" what do you mean by that? I have a zip file and using the commands that i have on my question, i try to upload it to a ckan installation. how can i use what you just said?